# How to make text transition by animation upon button press?

Tags: flutter, animation, math, fade

Currently, when opacity = 0 & button is pressed, opacity becomes one. But I would like the button also having the function to turn opacity to zero and back to one when opacity is already one.

How can this be made possible ? Thanks

Im thinking it has something to do with tween? Eg. When the button is pressed, the opacity of the quote turns to zero and back to 1 (duration of one second).
But Im not sure how to write that.

Attached below is the main chunk of the code that's involved in this action:

```
  double opacity1 = 0.0;


String quoteCat1 = List1[Random().nextInt(List1.length)];

  void generateConvoTopic1() {
    setState(() {
      quoteCat1 = List1[Random().nextInt(List1.length)];
    });
  }

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   
    return Scaffold(

...

body: ...
              
                AnimatedOpacity(
                    opacity: opacity1,
                    duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                    child:Text(quoteCat1),
              ]),
...
ElevatedButton(
...
onPressed: () {
                      generatequoteCat1();
                      opacity1 = 1.0;
                      opacity2 = 0.0;
                      opacity3 = 0.0;
                    },),

      
...
```

Comment: You can use `Future.deleyed` as well ! so that when you make the opacity zero when it is already one and then put the code where you again making the opaicty to one in the future.deleyed function for the duration of one second so that that code will be executed after one second when your opacity is first changed from one to zero and then after one second or whatever time you wants to choose, the opacity will be one again from that future.delateyed function!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to switch between two values, you could use a boolean and make your button switch its value. In the `toggleOpacity` function is also an example of how to animate back the function as @Aayush said using a Future.delayed.

Now if you want more complex animations, or infinite ones, you should use an animationController to have full control of it

See example:

```dart
class Demo extends StatefulWidget {
  Demo({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _DemoState createState() => _DemoState();
}

class _DemoState extends State<Demo> {
  bool visible = true;
  var animateBack=false;

  void toggleOpacity() {
    setState(() {
      visible = !visible;
    });
if(animateBack)    
Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1)).then((value) {
     setState(() {
       visible = !visible;

     });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: AnimatedOpacity(
          opacity: visible ? 1 : 0,
          duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
          child: Text(
            'Now you see me',
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: toggleOpacity,
        child: Icon(visible?Icons.wb_sunny:Icons.wb_sunny_outlined),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you.  But I have updated my code to include something more. It's regarding the tween animation of text as seen in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68328866/how-to-tween-animate-a-text-from-opacity-1-to-0-and-back-to-1-with-one-button
By any chance you know anything about this?